# VTC curve of cmos when Id does not saturate

Tags: cmos, nmos, pmos

For transistors, if the Id does not saturate at the saturation region (nmos: Vds>Vsg-Vt, pmos: Vsd>Vgs-|Vt|), but follow a linear relationship. How will the inverter VTC curve change?

I am thinking when Vin switches from 0->1, the nmos turns on, but Vout drops more sharper than before, coz at a same VDS the current Id is larger than before.

when the Vin switches from 1->0, the pmos turns on, the Vout increases more sharper than before, coz at the same VSD the current Id is larger than before.

but the correct answer seems to be that the slope of transition curve is smaller?
am I making anything wrong here?

Comment: What does "coz" mean? Keep in mind that this is an English-only site. Can you draw a graph of the VTC in question for us, perhaps for the usual case and for the specific case you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

\$I_{ds}=\beta (V_{gs}-V_t)^2/2\$
if both Pch and Nch have |Vt| = 1.5 V , Vdd=3.3V and \$\beta=0.05\$ then RdsOn = 11\$\Omega\$ at 3.3V with a wide tolerance >25% and both conduct when Vin = 50% with a supply current of 10 mA until the inverted rail is reached.   Thus you may confirm if the formula is correct for Rn+Rp=3.3V/10 mA.  This impulse current is why every CMOS IC needs a decoupling cap placed near it.

\$g_m=1/RdsOn\$ determines the gain and the slew rate is first limited by the Miller and gate capacitance.